# C# Compare If Values In An Array are Found a SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, arrays, dataset

I am trying to do some group comparison in my web application and want to see if the current user is in a certain list of groups that I have stored in a SQL table.  I currently am getting my groups in an array using this method...

```
   public ArrayList GetGroups()
    {
     ArrayList groups = new ArrayList();
    foreach (System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference group in
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups)
    {
    groups.Add(group.Translate(typeof
    (System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString());
    }
    return groups;
    }
```

From here I can check if the user is in a certain group by doing this

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al = GetGroups();


            foreach (string s in al)
            {
                if (s == "some_group")
                {                    
                    //do this;

            }

                }
```

I can get it working for individual or even a few groups but I have a SQL table with about 20 groups in it and I just wanted to use some sort of comparison between the array and my SQL table.  I tried using a dataset and comparing them but I was not able to get that working.  Any advice is appreciated I am just learning how to work in C#. Thank you.

Comment: What about trying out LINQ?

Comment: what about using al.Contains("some_group")  ? you would get rid of that foreach.

Comment: I would be fine with using LINQ. I'll see if I can pull anything together. I have never used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things I noticed from your code:

1. There is no reason to use `ArrayList`. Instead use a `List<T>` where in your case, `T` would be `string`. This provides type safety and better performance.
2. You create a new instance of the `ArrayList` class and then you assign the result of `GetGroups` to that variable (`al`). You initialized an instance of the `ArrayList` for no purpose, you already created the instance in the `GetGroups` method.

I'm not quite sure what comparison you are wanting to do between the user groups and the SQL groups. Feel free to add more details, but you can do a very basic contains check like so:

```
List<string> userGroups = GetUserGroups();
List<string> sqlGroups = GetSqlGroups();

foreach (var sqlGroup in sqlGroups)
{

    // case-sensitive check
    if (userGroups.Contains(sqlGroup))
    {
        // the user has one of the SQL groups
    }

    // case-insensitive check
    if (userGroups.Contains(sqlGroup, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // the user has one of the SQL groups
    }

}
```

You can get more advanced using LINQ or even if you need to consider cAsE sEnsiTiviTY, but you'll need to provide more details for that.

Comment: Okay I think I am on the right track now.  I have both the userGroups and sqlGroups properly loaded into their Lists and now I am working on comparison.  What would be your recommendation to do compare and ignore case? I just need to check if the users group is contained in my list of SQL groups but I have no guarantee they were all entered with the proper case!

Comment: @Ty53ler Edited code to show how you can do a case-insensitive check.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> userGroups = new List<string>();
List<string> sqlGroups = new List<string>();
var containedGroups = sqlGroups.Where(item=>userGroups.Contains(item));
```

Generic List is better than ArrayList if you can make sure your data type.